# about pattern pattern = r"(.+) \1" and pattern = r"(.+) \2" in python

Tags: python, design-patterns

Can you please explain these pattern for me?  pattern = r"(.+) \1" and pattern = r"(.+) \2"

when i use  the following script, there is no problem:

```
import re
pattern = r"(.+) \1"
match = re.match(pattern, "word word")
if match:
   print ("Match 1")
```

but when i change the pattern to  r"(.+) \2" it rise an error. please explain exactly  what is this pattern mean.

```
import re
pattern = r"(.+) \2"
match = re.match(pattern, "egg egg egg")
if match:
   print ("Match 1")
```

Comment: `\1` is a back-reference; it'll match whatever group 1 matched. There is only **one group** in your pattern, so `\2` can't reference anything.

Answer (score 3):

`\1` is equivalent to `re.search(...).group(1)`, the first parentheses-delimited expression inside of the regex. Since there is no `2nd group` in your `regex`, that's why it is not working.
If you add 2nd group, then it will work

```
import re
pattern = r"(.+)() \2"
match = re.match(pattern, "egg egg egg")
if match:
   print ("Match 1")
Match 1
```